# Creating text files

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to make a Mac app.
To create txt files

```
-(IBAction)create:(id)sender {
    system("/Users/pedrocosta/Desktop/");
    system ("touch Mytxtfile.txt");
```

but how can I link these two expressions?

```
system("/Users/pedrocosta/Desktop/");
system ("touch Mytxtfile.txt");
```

Because when I try the app the computer only do:

```
system("/Users/pedrocosta/Desktop/");
```

Comment: please ask a real question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create a file, you should use the Cocoa API:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"/Users/pedrocosta/Desktop/Mytxtfile.txt" contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

If for some reason you want to use the `system` function, then why don't you try:

```
system("/usr/bin/touch /Users/pedrocosta/Desktop/Mytxtfile.txt");
```